# Table objects used Cake\ORM\Table instead of a concrete class: How to fix?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this warning in my CakePHP logs:

> The following Table objects used Cake\ORM\Table instead of a concrete
>   class:
>
> Jobs

Here is my controller class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

/**
 * Jobs Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\JobsTable $Jobs
 */
class JobsController extends AppController
{
    public $name = 'Jobs';

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //Set Query Options
        $options = array(
            'order' => array('Jobs.created' => 'desc'),
            'limit' => 1
        );

        //Get Jobs info
        $getjobs = TableRegistry::get('Jobs');
        $jobs = $getjobs->find('all',$options);
        $this->set('jobs',$jobs);
    }
}
```

Is there another/better way to access my db and read data from it?
I'm using latest version of CakePHP.
It's my first time using it, so I would like to know if there is a better way to do this MySQL interaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside of src/Model/Table/, define a class named JobsTable.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class JobsTable extends Table
{
    // ... Jobs Table logic defined here
}
```

This should build your Table object from TableRegistry::get() with this class rather than the delegated Cake class.

You can learn more about building Table objects in CakePHP 3.x here:

[CakePHP 3.x Table Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html)

Comment: Does this mean that i don't have to change anything in my controller? Just add a model?

Comment: When you use TableRegistry::get(), it immediately tries to load the corresponding model from the Table folder.  If it fails to find that model, it will delegate to the base Table class, which will assume the SQL table you are using is the underscored, inflected version of the model name you passed into ::get().